# ubuntu 20.04 can " zfs-auto-snapshot" v.s. zsys

Tags: 20.04, zfs, snapshot

The package zfs-auto-snapshot is not installed by default.
zsys is a minimally documented/incomplete snapshot management, which is the default. In particular it is unclear **how and when snapshots are deleted**.

Can I use the well documented **zfs-auto-snapshot** alongside  **zsys**. I like zsys boot and scrub functions. I am looking at zfs-auto-snapshot because it it a more transparent package. Are they conflicting packages? can I also use zfs-auto-snapshot to manage zsys snapshots (since I do not know exactly what it is doing).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMO you would be best off uninstalling zsys and zfs-auto-snapshot and using sanoid instead. It is very mature, reasonably well documented, and "just works".